# Split String Based On Multiple Special Characters

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substring

Below is a string I have which is combined together using four (`@ # &`) different special characters. Using each of the special character I want to extract the value/variable in between the special character.

**Input String**

```
data <- "Vdm@FVDDM_HL#OV_L&28000016"
```

Using `@ # &` I want to extract characters `Vdm`, `FVDDM_HL`, `OV_L` and `28000016`. I can use `sub(".*&", "", data)` but it will work better only on the last character value i.e `28000016`. After this if I use `sub(".*#", "", data)`, then it will extract both `OV_L` and `28000016`, but I want only `OV_L`.

There are also cases where input string is like below where two special characters are together `# and &`, but I still want to extract the `blank` in between `# and &`.

```
data <- "Vdm@FVDDM_HL#&28000016"
```

Is there a better way to extract values before, after or in between the special characters using `sub()`? **I don't want to extract together but one value at a time.**

Comment: Maybe `strsplit(data, "@|#|&")` or `unlist(strsplit(data, "@|#|&")`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns - Thank you. It should work. I think you are missing ending `)` from `unlist()` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strsplit`

```
> unlist(strsplit("Vdm@FVDDM_HL#OV_L&28000016", "\\W+"))
[1] "Vdm"      "FVDDM_HL" "OV_L"     "28000016"
> unlist(strsplit("Vdm@FVDDM_HL#&28000016", "\\W+"))
[1] "Vdm"      "FVDDM_HL" "28000016"
```

\W+ will match for at least one character

Comment: .@Sonny - Thank you. How is `"\\W"` able to split based on special characters? I mean, can you explain how this solution works code wise. It's correct though.

Comment: The `\w` metacharacter is used to find a word character.
A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.

Comment: W stands for Symbols, Refer this [link](https://help.relativity.com/9.3/Content/Relativity/Regular_expressions/Regular_expression_metacharacters.htm)